# Git merging into branch with changes to both since split

Tags: git, github, merge

Suppose I am on branch `master` and run `git branch dev` - this will create a new branch.

Then I make some changes to branch `dev`

Then I make some completely different changes to branch `master`, but some are to the same file

```
   master -> (arbitrary # of commits) -> master*
        \
         \___ dev -> (arbitrary # of commits) -> dev*
```

And now I run `git merge`

Changes made to `dev` will be added to `master`

**Q1)** Will changes made to `master` be overwritten?

**Q2)** What if the changes made to `dev` are to the same file as the changes made to `master`?

**Q2b)** What if I want changes to one branch to take priority?

For example: `test.js` was changed on lines 2-7 in `master` but it was changed on lines 5-10 in `dev`.

What if I want the changes in `master` to take priority. That is, I want this `merge` to ignore all changes to `test.js` from `dev`

Answer (score 1):

Git merge does exactly as it says. It'll merge your changes.

`$ git checkout master
$ git merge dev`

This will merge all your changes from dev into master. Depending on the severity of the merge it'll create a separate merge commit (you'll have to step through that commit and write a commit message).

- If you modify the same line (or same critical sections) in both branches, you'll get a merge conflict (`git merge --abort` if you start panicking).
- If you modify the same file, but not the same lines, it'll just merge the changes together

This is a great example for why a test suite is important. It's a fast way to see when merges have gone bad, because your tests might fail on bad merges.

The [documentation for git merge](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) has great examples, too.